# Building Ubuntu touch: cannot obtain manifest

Tags: ubuntu, building, ubuntu-touch

When i am trying to build Ubuntu touch i get the following error.

```
youri@youri-virtual-machine:~/Desktop$ mkdir phablet
youri@youri-virtual-machine:~/Desktop$ phablet-dev-bootstrap phablet/
INFO:phablet-dev-bootstrap:Changing to workdir /home/youri/Desktop/phablet
INFO:phablet-dev-bootstrap:Initializing repository
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
Get https://code-review.phablet.ubuntu.com/p/aosp/platform/manifest.git
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  2399  100  2399    0     0   7513      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7513
Invalid clone.bundle file; ignoring.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Unavailable
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Unavailable
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: cannot obtain manifest https://code-review.phablet.ubuntu.com/p/aosp/platform/manifest.git
ERROR:phablet-dev-bootstrap:Error while trying to sync repository
```

Also updated the repo executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this bug posting, the severs needs to be restarted.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phablet-tools/+bug/1610650